# error on returning a class by wcf

Tags: wcf, class, config

I've been struggling with this error for a while:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   ....8332/Service1.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint
>   binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP
>   request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the
>   service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

I traced the error and apparently it's something to do with the binding or the connection that I can't figure out how to solve.
 ..I am putting the class and the config files below.please guide me.thanks in advance.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class filepack
    {
        string  filesize = "0";
        int  accesspermitid =0;
         System.IO.Stream str ;


         [DataMember]
         public System.IO.Stream Filestr
         {
             get { return str; }
             set { str = value; }
         }

        [DataMember]
        public string Filesize
        {
            get { return filesize; }
            set { filesize = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int Accesspermitid
        {
            get { return accesspermitid; }
            set { accesspermitid = value; }
        }


    }

  <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />

        </startup>

        <system.serviceModel>

            <behaviors>
                <endpointBehaviors>

                    <behavior name="debugbeh">
                        <dataContractSerializer />
                    </behavior>
                </endpointBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="500000000"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000">
                        <security mode="None">
                            <message algorithmSuite="Default" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:8332/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="debugbeh"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                    contract="vcpservice.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </client>

        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>







    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
        <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                  switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                  propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
              <add name="sdt"
                  type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                  initializeData="c:\\logclientHOST.svclog"  />
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources>
      </system.diagnostics>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="mybinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="52428800"
              maxBufferSize="500000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000" />
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <diagnostics>
          <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
        </diagnostics>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
              <dataContractSerializer />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"
                httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding" httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: I beleive the problem is due to Stream.. what derived stream are you using in programming. I would reccomend that you use the actual stream type and test

Comment: the other answer below is suggesting the same for my case,but as I commented on him, I need to deactivate streaming for other methods im exposing on my server in runtime..how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a stream. You will need to either materialize your stream into a real data object (string or byte array for example) by reading it to the end before sending or if you really want streaming (which I doubt) you can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: as the matter of fact i'm transferring files through this stream..so probably that would be the thing I should use..but the thing is that file transfer is only one of the functionalities of my app i.e, the other methods do not need streaming ,so I should not use it for them.so the question is how can I activate/deactivate streaming by code at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be solved by removing the stream from the class and returning it separately!
but I don't know how did it help to solve it!